# How do I pass the data from the checked List Tile to the next page (Basket) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I previously used a Listview to present my data, but I was advised to use a Checkbox List tile now I'm stuck on how to pass data. I want to pass the selected/checked List tile's data to the next page (Basket). How do I do that, please help me.

I am new to Flutter.

The Main Method Class

```
import 'package:cart_app1/Basket.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyHomePage(),
        Basket.routeName: (context) => Basket(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The product list class

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Map<String, bool> values = {
    "GIN COCKTAILS \nClover Club \t  R65": false,
    "Beers & Ciders \nHeineken NRB \t R29": false,
    "Vodka \nCiroc \t R35": false,
    "Vodka \nCruz Vodka \t R30": false,
    "COGNAC \nHennesy \t R40": false,
    "Tequilla \nEl Jimador \t R30": false,
    "Non-Alcoholic \nSoft-Drink \t R20": false,
    "WHISK[E]Y \nJohnie Walker Red \t R25": false,
  };

  var toggle = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("The Wing Republic"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context)
                  .pushNamed(Basket.routeName, arguments: values);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: values.keys.map((String key) {
          return CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text(key),
            subtitle: Text(""),
            isThreeLine: false,
            value: values[key],
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                values[key] = value;
              });
            },
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Basket Method

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Basket extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/Basket';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, bool>;
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `arguments` in `pushNamed` method.

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Basket.routeName, arguments: values);
```

On the receiving end, use `ModalRoute` to get the values.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Basket extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/Basket';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, bool>;
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Routes in MyApp is incorrect. If you want to use `routes`, you can't use `home` property. Instead of `home` specify `initialRoute`.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyHomePage(),
        Basket.routeName: (context) => Basket(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The Solution throws an error that says "Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/Basket", {GIN COCKTAILS"

Comment: I added "routes: {Basket.routeName:(Context) =>Basket(),}" in the Main widget,  it now goes to the Basket without throwing an error but it shows a blank screen

Comment: I am really clueless on routes since I am new to Flutter.  I just want a solution that would work not specifically routes. your  updated answer throws this error in the brackets ( "If the home property is specified, the routes table cannot include an entry for "/", since it would be redundant.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart': 
Failed assertion: line 210 pos 10: 'home == null ||
         !routes.containsKey(Navigator.defaultRouteName)' ")

Comment: Remove `home` property. In my answer there is no `home` property.

Comment: I removed it, its fine now but I still can't pass data to the Basket page

Comment: Can you add relevant code? I'm sure you're missing something. You can edit your question.

Comment: I have updated my question. I want to know how do I pass the data from the checkList to be viewed in the Basket page

Comment: `final data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, bool>;` try printing this value in Basket page.

Comment: I already had this line in my Basket page, what do you mean by printing?

Comment: Log it and check it's output.

Comment: It prints the the whole list in Curly braces

Comment: That's the value. That means it's getting the value. Use it and render the `body` of Scaffold using other widgets.